# After disabling OWA Light using Set-OWAMailboxPolicy, how can users who have set OWA Light as a preference regain access to OWA?

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

If I use `Set-OWAMailboxPolicy -OwaLightEnabled $false -Identity Default` to disable OWA Light, anyone who has gone in to display settings -> Outlook Web App Version and selected OWA Light is then presented with a "Can't access Outlook Web App" error page if they try to log in (Actually, anyone using the same browser will see this as this error will now be the cached page when they go to OWA). Is there a way for an administrator or the user to reset their preference short of the administrator allowing the user to access OWA Light and the user changing their preference?

Adding `owa/?layout=premium` to the URL doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/75823.aspx

> 1. Disable OWA feature for the users with PowerShell, like this: Set-CASMailbox -Identity user1@contoso.com -OWAEnabled $false
> 2. Enable OWA feature for the users with PowerShell, like this: Set-CASMailbox -Identity user1@contoso.com -OWAEnabled $true

That seems to clear out the OWA Light preference, though, if it's done after disabling OWA Light the browser will still show a cached copy of the error page.

Comment: This seemed to work for my first test with an individual user, but I went back testing some powershell with groups of users and it no longer seems to be working.